# using $filter in providers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following provider

```
(function (angular) {
    var listing_app = angular.module('TEST.Providers', []);
    listing_app.provider('TESTAdapter', ['$filter',function ($filter) {

        var self = this;
        this.$get = function () {
            return {
                "convert": function (result) {
                    //do something
                    return result;
                }
            };
        };
    }]);



})(angular);
```

I get the following error, Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $filter . I cannot understand why we cant inject $filter in the provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually inject right on the $get function like this:

```
this.$get = ['$filter', function ($filter) {
```

Comment: It's where the dependency injection is done for providers, and able to be enforced. Since $get serves as the creation of the service, it is analogous to the main functions for controllers and factories and such. There should be no reason to rely on other services before creation time of your provider.

Comment: what is the difference between this way and doing how  2dimiric

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19720419/2728255 seems to say that it's because providers are instantiated before the factories and so a provider has to depend only on other providers. So you can only inject some things there. http://jsfiddle.net/utJ9q/1 shows it with $filterProvider. http://jsfiddle.net/utJ9q/2/ shows the failure with factory. For reference, here is the code where they added array style injection to the provider https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1452.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject filters but you need to use the suffix "Filter" with their names.
E.g., filterFilter, dateFilter, someSortFilter, etc.

So in this case:

`listing_app.provider('TESTAdapter', ['filterFilter',function ($filter) {`