# angular how to pass an object from controller to service

Tags: angularjs

i have this in my controller that retrieve and object inside the $scope.formData.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('loginController', function($scope, Authentication){
$scope.formData = {};

$scope.processForm = function(){
    Authentication.login($scope.formData);
    //$http({
    //    method  : 'GET',
    //    url     : 'http://localhost:8888/employees/login',
    //    params: $scope.formData
    //})
    //    .success(function(respond){
    //        $scope.state.go('main');
    //    })
}

})
```

in the service js i have a method called login that it suppose to retrive the data sent from the controller, but so far im getting a value null when i do console.log(formData),.

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Authentication', function($http){

    this.login = function(formData){
    console.log(formData);
    return $http({
            method  : 'GET',
            url     : 'http://localhost:8888/employees/login',
            params: formData
        })
}

    return null;
})
```

this is my html

```
<ion-view view-title="login">
<ion-content class="padding has-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-50 col-offset-25">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                    <form ng-submit="processForm()">
                        <div class="list">
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="formData.AccessKey" required="true">
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="formData.Password" required="true">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button class="button button-full button-positive">
                            Sign me in
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

i get this console error Cannot read property 'login' of null

my app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])
```

Comment: Can you provide your html code?

Comment: Did you try passing the `formData` to `processForm()`? E.g. `processForm(formData)` then assigning it in the controller?

Comment: I haven't used angular in a long time, but shouldn't your factory `return this`?

Comment: i get this console error Cannot read property 'login' of null

Comment: That's an interesting pattern I hadn't seen before - create all your controllers in 'module.controllers' and services in 'module.services'. Then create a 'module' module that takes both sub-modules as dependencies...

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code correctly, the problem is that you are using 2 different modules.

Try to use same modules for controller

```
 angular.module('sameModule', [])

    .controller('loginController', function($scope, Authentication){
...}
```

and service/factory like

```
     angular.module('sameModule', [])

.factory('Authentication', function($http){...
}
```

or to inject module from service/factory to module of controller:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['starter.services'])
```

Read also this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719729/angularjs-injecting-factory-from-another-module-into-a-provider), it could help you to understand the idea...

Hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: in my app.js im including both modules

Comment: Try to use same modules for controllers and factory.

Answer (score 0):

i found my issue

```
.factory('Authentication', function($http){

return {
    login:  function(formData) {
        $http({
            method  : 'GET',
            url     : 'http://localhost:8888/employees/login',
            params: formData
        })
        .success(function(respond){
            console.log(respond);
        })
    }
};
```