# Injecting lodash into Angular provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I've seen several questions about injecting lodash/underscore into controllers, but I need to put it into a custom provider. I can't seem to figure out how to do that. There is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719729/angularjs-injecting-factory-from-another-module-into-a-provider) that has an accepted answer, but I can't figure out how to re-purpose that technique for my situation.

I'm injecting lodash into angular as a separate module:

```
angular.module("lodash", [])
.factory("_", ($window) => {
    return $window._;
});
```

How would I modify or add to this in order to make lodash injectable into my provider?

Comment: Take a look at how this one works or just use it https://github.com/rockabox/ng-lodash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To inject Lodash to both service providers and service instances use

```
angular.module("lodash", [])
.constant("_", window._);
```

instead . There are scenarios where using `$window` abstraction may be beneficial, but here it can be safely omitted.