# Provide factory of one module to another module

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have just started working on Angularjs and facing a problem in calling the factory defined in other module. Actually I need to clean the code so I have to build all the functionalities in one js file and I have to use them in my main js file where I have defined my controllers. I have made a simple code to understand the problem. Thanks in advance

Following is the Html file:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5"  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="function.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="MyServiceModuleOne">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
      <button type="button" ng-click="getFn()"> Test  </button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Following is script.js file

```
var myModule= angular.module('MyServiceModuleTwo',['MyServiceModuleOne']);
myModule.controller('TestController', ['$scope', 'notify',    function($scope, notify){
  $scope.getFn = function() {
    notify.sampleFun();
  }
}]);
```

Following is function.js file:-

```
var myModule = angular.module('MyServiceModuleOne', []);
myModule.factory('notify',  function() {
  return {
    sampleFun: function() {
      alert('hi');
    }   
   };
});
```

Comment: So what exactly your problem

Comment: This is not working. I am not able to provide sampleFun to the other file. I need help as I am new to AngularJs

Comment: your root module should include all the related dependency 
so main problem is in `ng-app="MyServiceModuleOne"` => `ng-app="MyServiceModuleTwo"`

Comment: Why you need to defined multiple module since in your view you're using one module only.

Comment: In view I am not able to declare two modules because it gives error. Now is this possible to define only one module and declare factory in other file and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of changes needed.
You are referencing `MyServiceModuleOne` as root module, but the controller you are referencing is in `MyServiceModuleTwo`.

So change your ng-app from `MyServiceModuleOne` to `MyServiceModuleTwo`.

I've updated the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/NDiZu5mSjt0z4IWrw366?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I am applying the same technique to my real code but I am getting the following error. Please help:-
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module App due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'App' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$injector/nomod?p0=allianzApp

Comment: I guess you are referencing ng-app with `allianzApp`. so if you change the ng-app name you should also change the corresponding module name in your script file.

Comment: The real error is:-
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module allianzApp due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module second due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'second' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. I just changed it here while pasting error. so there is no problem with module name or app name.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar share your plnkr and update the question. so that we can look into

Comment: Hi is this possible to send you an email? or I have to make plunker?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar You can simply edit my plnkr and share the updated link. Don't hurry, first read the basics in angularjs.org and know the concepts

Comment: Hi, I have added three files to plunker. You will not be able to run but you can still know the problem in the code.
http://plnkr.co/edit/cB9EcnDAGudaAy4DoVI7?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137342/discussion-between-muhammad-umar-and-gangadhar-jannu).

Comment: @MuhammadUmar. There are quite a lot of changes required for your plnkr. First read the documents and learn about folder structure. **Mostly the issues are related to spelling mistakes** Here is the updated [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oIPdWs?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me that where are the spelling issues? because if you are talking about file names then in my code spellings are not wrong. But can you please mention mistakes? The folder structure is also okay in the main project. I just added 3 files in plunker

Comment: I think I am facing this kind of issue given in the following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719729/angularjs-injecting-factory-from-another-module-into-a-provider?rq=1